# Tileserver-gl custom styles

Tags: vector-tiles

How to load custom style (mapbox GL JSON) when running a docker container of tileserver-gl?
I have my own MBTILES vector tiles made with tippecanoe and Ive made a stylesheet.
Want to load that JSON file to use with the mbtiles. 
I need to rasterize (request PNG) these tiles for a mobile client that does not support vector tiles.